# Why does Redis show the top most invalidated tags as all "config.system.menu-***" items>

Tags: caching

Drupal 9.5 - Redis on Pantheon. We are stuggling with site performance and I see that the Most Invalidated Redis Cache Tags are all super high. This can't be normal, right?

Any ideas on how to resolve these high invalidations?

[image]

Comment: In a quick check of the code dependencies, I can only see a connection with rebuilding of routes which is part of rebuilding the cache. You should see in the database more cache tags, not only those covered by Redis. Do you find more with similar invalidation counts? Are they also connected with cache rebuilds?

Comment: Thank you 4uk4 - You're suggesting that this *may* not be an issue with the super-high invalidation counts for the menus? The site is on Panteheon and I'm not sure how we can inspect the cache tables there. Would it be worth while to export the 2gb+ db and import it somewhere where we can inspect it?

Comment: You don't have access to the SQL database to check the cachetags table?

Comment: It might be best to inspect the DB in-place rather than export it. I haven't used Pantheon for ages but last time I did, they (quite reasonably) stripped out the cache tables for exports, at least when done through the UI